# Tomcat VueJS axios: How to read a string passed through "data" in an axios POST method?

Tags: servlets, axios

I am making an axios POST call to a tomcat servlet. I see the string being sent as Request payload when I check Developer tools but I am not able to retrieve the string in Tomcat servlet.

When I test it with PHP, I am able to retrieve the json string.

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $json_str; //This works and displays the JSON string
```

This is what I have tried in the servlet, please let me know what might be wrong with my code.

### VueJs axios

```
axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: urltocall,
                    data: this.strjson,
                    params: {
                        'username': 'test1'
                    },
                    config: {
                        headers: {
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:1337',
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
                    }
                })
                    .then(function (response) { }
```

### Tomcat Servlet

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
            String str;
            while( (str = br.readLine()) != null ){ //Not entering this while loop, so "sb" is empty
                sb.append(str);
            }
```

"content-length' when checked in the servlet, shows the correct length of the string passed through "data", so that confirms that the string is available in the request object. But for some strange reason, the getReader() is not fetching the string.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was reading a parameter from request object before using the getReader() to extract the data. That was causing the data to be wiped out. When I shifted the getReader() to top, to give it the 1st access of info in request object, it worked just fine. Trivial fix but cost some time. Hope this helps someone.

### Wrong

```
String test = request.getParameter("test");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
String str;
while( (str = br.readLine()) != null ){
    sb.append(str);
}
```

### Right

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
String str;
while( (str = br.readLine()) != null ){
    sb.append(str);
}
String test = request.getParameter("test");
```